# from PIL import Image not working

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I have already installed `pillow` and I am trying to import Image as `from PIL import Image`.

However, it is giving me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Check pip list or pip freeze output.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages. Post the text directly here on SO instead.

Comment: Can you post the output for `sys.path`?

Comment: Thankyou for your advises. error got solved by uninstalling pillow and again installing it.

Comment: Great. Although my suggestion, since you have anaconda, create and work through an environment. It saves so much time and hassles.

Answer (score 0):

First yo need to install PIL by:-
$ pip install PIL

once the packages gets extracted use :

> > > from PIL import Image